# Objective C importing contact from email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, contacts

I want to import contact list from email.

Giving Email Id and Password in Objective C (iPhone Application).

Comment: To be clearer: do you want to import the names and email addresses directly from the emails received or do you want to import the contacts list from a webmail service such as Yahoo or Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the built in E-Mail-App, if that's what you meant. You can however access the address book. Take a look at the AdressBookUI framework.